# nodejs real time example

Tags: node.js, real-time

I found this http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2009/12/7/real-time-online-activity-monitor-example-with-node-js-and-websocket
I can start the server but accessing "iostat-client.html" displays "connection closed". Anyone from here tried this example? Or Does any one know other similar real time examples?
More specifically -

```
> # cat child3.js  
> spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
> 
> tail = spawn('tail -f
> /home/laks/ruby/txt.log');
> 
> tail.stdout.on("output",function(data){
> console.log(data); });
```

How to make sure ,output(its not working) from above appears over http on port 8080?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/2-webtail-nodejs-child-processes-and-http-chunked-encoding.html